# How to Hide the Column View on SharePoint Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have list in SharePoint online with classic view.

I have color indicators on that list:
[image]

I want to hide the "Alert Zone" field in the view. But what is when I remove it in the settings in SharePoint, my color indicators does not work.

Color Indicators: Green, Yellow, Red.

How do I hide this column view using java script, but my color indicator should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use SharePoint View CSR to hide a column.

```
(function () {
    
    function RemoveFields(ctx) {
        var fieldName = "Date"; // here Date is field or column name to be hide
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + fieldName + "]")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};
        ctxForm.OnPostRender = RemoveFields;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

[Soucre](https://riptutorial.com/sharepoint/example/26699/hide-column-from-sharepoint-list-view-using-csr-)